# Dropping tables using dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having trouble with my `SQL` stored procedure, specifically passing in `VARCHAR()` as a table name using it.

My code (not working) is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteUser 

 @Username VARCHAR(50)

    AS
    BEGIN

    --DROP THE SURF TABLE
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 
      FROM sysobjects 
      WHERE xtype='u' AND name=@Username + '_table') 
          DROP TABLE @Username + '_table'  

 END
GO
```

However, on execution it errors at the `DROP TABLE @Username + '_table'` line.

What could I be doing incorrectly?

I am using MS SQL Server 2008 if it matters, called from C#.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure DeleteUser, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near '@Username'. Line 21 is  the DROP TABLE line.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `DROP TABLE` statement can't be parametrised as you are trying. You would need dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @DynSql nvarchar(max) = 'DROP TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@Username + '_table');
EXEC(@DynSql);
```